# WidgetConfigurationIntent @Parameter sometimes cannot get a value

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

There is a code:

```
struct DataEntry: EntityQuery {
  func getData() async -> [Data] {
    do {
      let token = try ServiceData.getTokenThrows()
      let listData = try await ServiceData.fetchDataNew(token: token) // always return list data
      return listData
    } catch {
      return []
    }
  }
  
  func entities(for identifiers: [DataModel.ID]) async throws -> [DataModel] {
      return await getData().filter {
          identifiers.contains($0.id)
      }
  }
  
  func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [DataModel] {
      return await getData()
  }
  
  func defaultResult() async -> DataModel? {
    return await getData().first
  }
}
```

Sometimes during assembly, when changing user data, the data in WidgetConfiguration Intent @Parameter is not received, although they are in the console, and EntityQuery methods do not throw exceptions. Does anyone have any ideas?